# AVPlayerLayer is nil

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm capturing a video, after the capture is done I'm trying to preview the captured video on my AVPlayerLayer.

After capturing the video, I do save the url to DocumentsDirectory. This url is also saved in AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate's "***didFinishRecordingTo"*** function as "outputFileURL".

I wrote the code below to ***didFinishRecordingTo*** function.

Created an AVplayer with the relative url, created an AVPlayerLayer as *"previewLayer"* with corresponded AVPlayer. But still I'm printing the line below which says *"preview Layer nil"* I've also tried print(previewLayer) but it says that it is nil.

Why this might be happening?

Appreciate it

```
 private var previewLayer : AVPlayerLayer?

   let player = AVPlayer(url: outputFileURL)
    
    previewLayer? = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    previewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
    print(previewLayer)
    guard let previewLayer = previewLayer else {
        print("preview Layer nil")
        return
    }
    
    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer.player?.play()
    recordButton.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `?` from `previewLayer?` ( only in below line ) as it will make the line useless that defaults to

```
previewLayer? = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

nil = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
```

That leaves `previewLayer` nil , So make it

```
previewLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I'll accept this as answer.